# Is it possible Covering a Webview button with pure xamarin button and clicking it the website button also clicked?

Tags: xamarin, button, xamarin.forms, webview, cross-platform

i have a webview that loads a log in page in website then the button of the login in website was Covered by pure button in xamarin form.... when i click the pure xamarin button the Button of Log in page in website will also clicked ...

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It's better to use a hybrid webview

Comment: how can i interface the login button in website if i use hybrid webview???

Comment: You could use Custom Renderer . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview .

Comment: Could you share a picture of what you are trying to do?